# How to get files from multiple directories and displaying it in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

As stated in the questions. I want to read files from multiple directories and display all of it in a single datagridview. I've found one that having the same problem but that one is using List<>.AddRange to get the directories while I'm using string[]. Please help. Here is my code snippet to fetch the directory and files :

```
s1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FILE\7", "*.*");
```

and this is for reading it and filling it in a datagridview :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= s1.Length - 1; i++)
        {

            try
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
                    dt.Columns.Add("File_Type");
                    dt.Columns.Add("File_Size");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Create_Date");
                }

                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(s1[i]);
                FileSystemInfo sysInfo = new FileInfo(s1[i]);
                dr = dt.NewRow();

                dr["File_Name"] = sysInfo.Name;
                dr["File_Type"] = sysInfo.Extension;
                dr["File_Size"] = (info.Length / 1024).ToString();
                dr["Create_Date"] = sysInfo.CreationTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);


                if ((info.Length / 1024) > 1500000)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("" + sysInfo.Name + " had reach its size limit.");
                }



                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
                continue;
            }
        }

   }
```

Comment: Use System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("", "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories); to get directories and sub-directories file list.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @zenwalker. Do you know how to get files from multiple directories??

Comment: Multiple directories as in what? Sub-directories under a root directory or directories located in different paths alltogether? If later one, then you have to use multiple GetFiles API calls

Comment: What I meant is lets say I have these 3 paths : 
<ol>
1.C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FILE\9
2.C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FILE\7
3.C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FILE\Copy of 7

I want to read and display all the files that is in these 3 paths in a single datagridview.

Comment: cant you use the api i suggested with just C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FILE path. Since 9, 7 and Copy directories do exists in this File directory. But problem comes where if some other Directories do present. But you can filter them again via FileInfo with file as parameter and checking if the path has 9/7/3 in it.

Comment: ok my bad for pasting my experimental path. Sorry about that. The actual path doesn't share the same root. From what I've found, GetFiles API doesn't support any multiple path.

Comment: Yes true, thats what i said. In that case you have to use multiple API calls to get files from different paths. No other way AFAIK.

Comment: Probably is a typo, but you set the datasource inside the loop.

Comment: Steve, yup that's a typo. I just put it in the loop to test something out. 
@zenwalker, if I use multiple API, would it still be possible for me to display it in a single datagridview?Would it possible for me if I use array (e.g : s1[] = {path1,path2....} )

Comment: Append all the array content to one or use all array (3 string[]s) to fetch and fill your datagridview.

Comment: you have got an answer, which is the correct one, pls accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<string> s1 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FILE\7", "*.*").ToList<string>();
s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FILE\9", "*.*").ToList<string>());
```

and so on... then

foreach(string s in s1)
.....